# find_by function isn't successful eventhough it should

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, error-handling, find-by-sql

my programming team created an account activation function like in Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial. Now after a few weeks of coding the function stopped working. So that is the full function:

```
class AccountActivationsController < ApplicationController

#Dieser Controller ist notwendig, um einen neu registrierten Account via Aktivierungsmail zu aktivieren.

  def edit
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    if user && !user.activated? && user.authenticated?(:activation, params[:id])
      user.activate
      log_in user
      flash[:success] = "Account aktiviert!"
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Ungültiger Aktivierungslink"
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end
end
```

We get the danger message coming from the else loop. We tried to break the problem down into pieces and now we know that the condition:

```
user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
```

is not successful.

I would like to have some suggestions, why this activation link:

```
http://localhost:3000/account_activations/hX1eY83-wcs8VqZcPa0H=
3g/edit?email=3Dsami.khedira%40stud.uni-hannover.de
```

doesn't give the right information to find the User "sami.khedira@stud.uni-hannover.de" in the data base. We can see the user in the data base and the save function before worked. I also looked through an earlier version of the app, where it worked. I don't see any changes in the functions, so maybe something that we added somewhere destroyed the registration, but from my point of view there is nothing missing.

Additionally the password_reset function doesn't work as well.

The create User function from the user controller:

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      @user.send_activation_email
      flash[:info] = "Bitte öffnen Sie Ihr E-Mail Postfach, um den Account zu aktivieren."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Here is how we create the digest:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord


  # Activates an account.
  def activate
    update_columns(activated: true, activated_at: Time.zone.now)
  end

  # Sends activation email.
  def send_activation_email
    UserMailer.account_activation(self).deliver_now
  end

  # Sets the password reset attributes.
  def create_reset_digest
    self.reset_token = User.new_token
    update_columns(reset_digest:  User.digest(reset_token), reset_sent_at: Time.zone.now)
  end

  # Sends password reset email.
  def send_password_reset_email
    UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver_now
  end

  # Returns true if a password reset has expired.
  def password_reset_expired?
    reset_sent_at < 2.hours.ago
  end

  private

    # Converts email to all lower-case.
    def downcase_email
      self.email = email.downcase
    end

    # Creates and assigns the activation token and digest.
    def create_activation_digest
      self.activation_token  = User.new_token
      self.activation_digest = User.digest(activation_token)
    end

end
```

Views/User Mailer/Account_activation.html.erb:

```
<h1>Bachelorarbeitszuordnung</h1>

<p>Sehr geehrter Herr / Sehr geehrte Frau <%= @user.name %>,</p>

<p>
Sie haben sich für die Bachelorarbeit registriert! Klicken Sie auf den untenstehenden Link, um ihren Account zu aktivieren:
</p>

<%= link_to "Aktivieren", edit_account_activation_url(@user.activation_token,
                                                    email: @user.email) %>
```

User Mailer:

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer


  def account_activation(user)
    @user = user
    mail to: user.email, subject: "Account activation"
  end

  def password_reset(user)
    @user = user
    mail to: user.email, subject: "Password reset"
  end
end
```

Application Mailer:

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "noreply@stud.uni-hannover.de"
  layout 'mailer'
end
```

Here is the routes file, I already know by other users, that it is not perfect, but I currently don't know how to improve it. I read the guide on rails routing, but I don't see why my routing is not good:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :deadlines
  resources :preferences
  resources :institutes
  resources :users
  resources :admin, to: 'users#admin'

  get 'password_resets/new'
  get 'password_resets/edit'

  root 'static_pages#home'
  get '/home', to: 'static_pages#home'
  get '/help', to: 'static_pages#help'
  get '/about', to: 'static_pages#about'
  get '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
  get '/matching', to: 'static_pages#matching'
  get '/cockpit', to: 'static_pages#cockpit'

  get '/signup', to: 'users#new'
  post '/signup',  to: 'users#create'

  get '/performance_show', to: 'users#performance_show'
  get '/performance_update', to: 'users#performance_update'

  post 'preferences/create_all', to: 'preferences#create_all'

  get '/login', to: 'sessions#new'
  post '/login', to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'

  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]

  # Routes für die Buttons der GAMS Berechnung
  post 'read_matching', to: 'static_pages#read_matching'
  post 'delete_matching', to: 'static_pages#delete_matching'
  post 'optimize', to: 'static_pages#optimize'

  # Route für Button zum Löschen aller Studenten
  delete 'delete_all', to: 'users#delete_all'

  #Route für Page zum Löschen des eigenen Accounts.
  get 'delete_account', to: 'users#delete_account'
  delete 'delete_account_sure', to: 'users#delete_account_sure'

end
```

And here is my log. It starts with the registration of the user "Sami Khedira":

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-13 17:41:09 +0100
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"hbZ8A9CWC60nyXYd3nf6Dv0M+d/ViCp0PJ8AmG/fI5ZvyE+hFBt5n8W54gg9yNqZQTfSuOa8PyUD16a3qoRGsg==", "user"=>{"name"=>"Sami Khedira", "mat_number"=>"1234567", "email"=>"sami.khedira@stud.uni-hannover.de", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Erstelle meinen Account"}
  [1m[35m (1.0ms)[0m  [1m[36mbegin transaction[0m
  [1m[36mUser Exists (3.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER(?) LIMIT ?[0m  [["email", "sami.khedira@stud.uni-hannover.de"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35mSQL (0.8ms)[0m  [1m[32mINSERT INTO "users" ("name", "email", "created_at", "updated_at", "password_digest", "activation_digest", "mat_number") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)[0m  [["name", "Sami Khedira"], ["email", "sami.khedira@stud.uni-hannover.de"], ["created_at", "2018-03-13 16:41:10.395281"], ["updated_at", "2018-03-13 16:41:10.395281"], ["password_digest", "$2a$10$2BLl1RzF2SOPB9/S5y.oC.W3vUY64GX9jOtd9EfOhrhs3Wnd7Z0Ky"], ["activation_digest", "$2a$10$MaFRiFb195HRm8AQ14OU.ey5ds5qDvR9nznFLBgClNXM21VqQh0AK"], ["mat_number", 1234567]]
  [1m[35m (11.9ms)[0m  [1m[36mcommit transaction[0m
  Rendering user_mailer/account_activation.html.erb within layouts/mailer
  Rendered user_mailer/account_activation.html.erb within layouts/mailer (29.8ms)
  Rendering user_mailer/account_activation.text.erb within layouts/mailer
  Rendered user_mailer/account_activation.text.erb within layouts/mailer (7.8ms)
UserMailer#account_activation: processed outbound mail in 80.2ms
Sent mail to sami.khedira@stud.uni-hannover.de (31.7ms)
Date: Tue, 13 Mar 2018 17:41:11 +0100

From: noreply@stud.uni-hannover.de

To: sami.khedira@stud.uni-hannover.de

Message-ID: <5aa7ff27a2570_3afe126dc7462164@studi-VirtualBox.mail>

Subject: Account activation

Mime-Version: 1.0

Content-Type: multipart/alternative;

 boundary="--==_mimepart_5aa7ff279cbd7_3afe126dc74620d2";

 charset=UTF-8

Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit





----==_mimepart_5aa7ff279cbd7_3afe126dc74620d2

Content-Type: text/plain;

 charset=UTF-8

Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable



Sehr geehrter Herr Sami Khedira,

Sie haben sich f=C3=BCr die Bachelorarbeit registriert! Klicken Sie auf d=
en untenstehenden Link, um ihren Account zu aktivieren:

<a href=3D"http://localhost:3000/account_activations/hX1eY83-wcs8VqZcPa0H=
3g/edit?email=3Dsami.khedira%40stud.uni-hannover.de">Aktivieren</a>



----==_mimepart_5aa7ff279cbd7_3afe126dc74620d2

Content-Type: text/html;

 charset=UTF-8

Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3Dutf=
-8" />
    <style>
      /* Email styles need to be inline */
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Bachelorarbeitszuordnung</h1>

<p>Sehr geehrter Herr Sami Khedira,</p>

<p>
Sie haben sich f=C3=BCr die Bachelorarbeit registriert! Klicken Sie auf d=
en untenstehenden Link, um ihren Account zu aktivieren:
</p>

<a href=3D"http://localhost:3000/account_activations/hX1eY83-wcs8VqZcPa0H=
3g/edit?email=3Dsami.khedira%40stud.uni-hannover.de">Aktivieren</a>

  </body>
</html>


----==_mimepart_5aa7ff279cbd7_3afe126dc74620d2--


Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 1972ms (ActiveRecord: 65.1ms)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-13 17:41:11 +0100
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
  Rendering static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (22.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_rails_default.html.erb (604.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (7.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (3.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 765ms (Views: 755.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)  

Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-13 17:47:23 +0100
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
  Rendering static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (965.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_rails_default.html.erb (11813.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (66.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (194.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (53.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 14350ms (Views: 14125.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Thank you very much!

Edit:
User bkunzi01 recommended me to exchange (email: params[:email]) with params[:user][:email]. That gave me the following error:
[image: Error Message]

Logfile:

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-14 02:07:04 +0100
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"6vTYSvvGONUEC7hEP/C/AqEHAeQ+oQToqHQGKuBsM7ozw/N+w11mWnIb1x4Io5CWU/eYpYwncObyWWC+zKY4Jg==", "user"=>{"name"=>"Sami Khedira", "mat_number"=>"12345678", "email"=>"samikhedira@stud.uni-hannover.de", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Erstelle meinen Account"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (1.9ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER(?) LIMIT ?  [["email", "samikhedira@stud.uni-hannover.de"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (14.4ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("name", "email", "created_at", "updated_at", "password_digest", "activation_digest", "mat_number") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["name", "Sami Khedira"], ["email", "samikhedira@stud.uni-hannover.de"], ["created_at", "2018-03-14 01:07:04.901137"], ["updated_at", "2018-03-14 01:07:04.901137"], ["password_digest", "$2a$10$whjEx3oPnLxyNFZomWst4uCAPqweV0jBtN342mlx.sJwAm6A4JD7a"], ["activation_digest", "$2a$10$EG9MOsxQYUJC2//VGj6Iyu1CB7/39NP3mMpv1BjE2QrYx2WeZCM7K"], ["mat_number", 12345678]]
   (62.6ms)  commit transaction
  Rendering user_mailer/account_activation.html.erb within layouts/mailer
  Rendered user_mailer/account_activation.html.erb within layouts/mailer (9.2ms)
  Rendering user_mailer/account_activation.text.erb within layouts/mailer
  Rendered user_mailer/account_activation.text.erb within layouts/mailer (9.3ms)
UserMailer#account_activation: processed outbound mail in 142.7ms
Sent mail to samikhedira@stud.uni-hannover.de (116.4ms)
Date: Wed, 14 Mar 2018 02:07:05 +0100
From: noreply@stud.uni-hannover.de
To: samikhedira@stud.uni-hannover.de
Message-ID: <5aa875b964bd3_4c5f1f7f0d42644@studi-VirtualBox.mail>
Subject: Account activation
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="--==_mimepart_5aa875b94bfdf_4c5f1f7f0d4257f";
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


----==_mimepart_5aa875b94bfdf_4c5f1f7f0d4257f
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Sehr geehrter Herr Sami Khedira,

Sie haben sich f=C3=BCr die Bachelorarbeit registriert! Klicken Sie auf d=
en untenstehenden Link, um ihren Account zu aktivieren:

<a href=3D"http://localhost:3000/account_activations/WFJAfA0Ed4h-eL13PApg=
ng/edit?email=3Dsamikhedira%40stud.uni-hannover.de">Aktivieren</a>


----==_mimepart_5aa875b94bfdf_4c5f1f7f0d4257f
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3Dutf=
-8" />
    <style>
      /* Email styles need to be inline */
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Bachelorarbeitszuordnung</h1>

<p>Sehr geehrter Herr / Sehr geehrte Frau Sami Khedira,</p>

<p>
Sie haben sich f=C3=BCr die Bachelorarbeit registriert! Klicken Sie auf d=
en untenstehenden Link, um ihren Account zu aktivieren:
</p>

<a href=3D"http://localhost:3000/account_activations/WFJAfA0Ed4h-eL13PApg=
ng/edit?email=3Dsamikhedira%40stud.uni-hannover.de">Aktivieren</a>

  </body>
</html>

----==_mimepart_5aa875b94bfdf_4c5f1f7f0d4257f--

Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 1177ms (ActiveRecord: 128.8ms)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-14 02:07:05 +0100
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
  Rendering static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (6.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_rails_default.html.erb (234.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (12.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (1.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 305ms (Views: 301.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/account_activations/WFJAfA0Ed4h-eL13PApg=ng/edit?email=3Dsamikhedira%40stud.uni-hannover.de" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-14 02:07:44 +0100
Processing by AccountActivationsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"email"=>"3Dsamikhedira@stud.uni-hannover.de", "id"=>"WFJAfA0Ed4h-eL13PApg=ng"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)



NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):

app/controllers/account_activations_controller.rb:6:in `edit'
```

Comment: show how you generate the activation links

Comment: I added it to the post

Comment: `Started GET "/account_activations/3ntNspTHh-PVOYo9xIHS=cg/edit?email=3Dab1%40stud.uni-hannover.de" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-13 16:49:41 +0100` this link in your log indicates you did not encode the email at the right spot.  Your params currently looks like `Parameters: {"email"=>"ab1@stud.uni-hannover.de", "id"=>"3ntNspTHh-PVOYo9xIHS=cg"}` so the value of `params[:email]` is not encoded with 64bit therefore it cannot be decoded with 64bit.

Comment: Secondly revert the code in your mailer from `mail to: Base64.urlsafe_encode64(user.email)` back to `mail to: user.email`, you do not want to tell the mailer to send it to a 64bit converted hash.  We want the email to go out to the actual email.

Comment: So what do your routes look like for account_activations currently?  Please edit your current post and paste.  Thanks

Comment: My original post has the routes file added now. I want to add the encoding correctly now but I can't find a spot in my code where I can put it in. I thought it needs to be before the creation process (visible in the users.controller) but I can't find a point to edit the email information of the form, directly after it gets into the application. I thought the better way is to first of all solve the original problem and add more complexity by encoding the email afterwards.

Comment: You should be calling the params hash as params[:user][:email] since it's nested.  params[:email] shouldn't work as is.  Look at your parameters hash in the log you posted under the POST request by the server and you'll see it's nested.  user=> {email: value} needs to be called as params[:user][:email]

Comment: Ohh thanks god, that there is still somebody looking at this post. Now it's 2 am here in Germany and I still didn't get the solution. It woud be a big loss to cut out this functionality :(. So I tried it how you recommended. First of all thanks for trying, but it gave me a new error: "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass". I will add a picture and the log to the original post.

Comment: @Mostah, we can figure it out, it's not too difficult a problem, let's not give up on it.  So upon looking at the code further, I believe this is the code that is generating your activation_link, and here is where you should do your 64bitENCODING of the email: `<%= link_to "Aktivieren", edit_account_activation_url(@user.activation_token, email: @user.email) %>` change that to: `<%= link_to "Aktivieren", edit_account_activation_url(@user.activation_token, email: Base64.urlsafe_encode64(@user.email)) %>` and revert the code back to using `params[:email]` not `params[:user][:email]`

Comment: @bkunzi01, this is his the params hash he is dealing with and it is not nested:  `Parameters: {"email"=>"3Dsamikhedira@stud.uni-hannover.de", "id"=>"WFJAfA0Ed4h-eL13PApg=ng"}`, so `params[:email]` is the correct way to grab the email in this case.

Answer (score 3):

You could convert the email and make it url safe like below.  You should be alright as long as you are verifying the uniqueness of all the emails in your database.  Hope this helps.

```
Base64.urlsafe_encode64("uglas@stud.uni-hannover.de")
# "dWdsYXNAc3R1ZC51bmktaGFubm92ZXIuZGU=" 

Base64.urlsafe_decode64("dWdsYXNAc3R1ZC51bmktaGFubm92ZXIuZGU=")
#  "uglas@stud.uni-hannover.de"
```

So wherever you are generating your activation link, make the 64bit conversion there so that the new link will now look like:

```
http://localhost:3000/account_activations/9rxXuiQEEXmeOnqcS_m-=
VQ/edit?email="dWdsYXNAc3R1ZC51bmktaGFubm92ZXIuZGU="
```

And now when you are getting your `params[:email]` you can simply convert it back like so:

```
user = User.find_by(Base64.urlsafe_decode64(params[:email]))
```

Comment: We verify the uniqueness like that in the model:     VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@(stud.uni-hannover.de|wiwi.uni-hannover.de)+\z/i
    validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}

Comment: Yes, I am fine with my validation, but the problem of the unsuccessful "find_by" still remains

Comment: ok so let's start with this.... first of all you should only edit your original post to reflect any changes you want to make to your question so it's easier and more organized so that the community can help you answer your question more quickly.  So please delete all of your posts that are answers and I will start leaving my comments on your original question which you should be editing.  So my next comments will be up there.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by setting the View/Mailer back to an older version.

Here you can see the difference between a successful link at the top and a false one at the bottom!

http://localhost:3000/account_activations/iTIWL74dAzPlsVckrOc6Uw/edit?email=dana%40stud.uni-hannover.de

http://localhost:3000/account_activations/iTIWL74dAzPlsVckrOc6Uw/edit?ema=il=3Ddana%40stud.uni-hannover.de

The suggestion from the beginning that the 3D causes the problem was right. I didn't even change the activation link. It was enough to put a German letter "ü" in the email text. That fucked up the link to. I don't really understand that connection but now everything is fine. I hope that someone in the future can profit from my experiences.

Kind regards to everyone who helped, you are heroes!

Comment: I just saw this, glad you got it working.  But if you get the chance see my last comment above.